# Excel SUMIF between dates and times

Tags: excel, date, time, sumifs

I have dates in column B. I want to add all the prices in another sheet (logs) if the dates in the rows are in between the date in B2 and B3. it works fine. but the problem is in B colomn. i also have time and it doesnt take the time into consideration. the date time is in this format: 2013-09-16 04:00

```
=SUMIFS(logs!G:G,logs!D:D,">="&$B2,logs!D:D,"<="&$B3)
```

How can i make excel take the date and time into consideration?

The following is the weekly sheet: total is column F.

```
Week #  Week Of       Total
1           2013-09-16 04:00  881
2           2013-09-23 04:00  416
3           2013-09-30 04:00  0
```

The following is sheet logs. Price is column G, requested datetime is column D

```
reqested_datetime   Duration    Mileage Price
2013-09-20 18:01    00:15:35    2.65    $23.00
2013-09-20 19:15    00:32:55    4.12    $42.00
2013-09-20 21:09    00:13:42    3.5     $25.00
2013-09-20 22:31    00:09:21    2.75    $19.00
2013-09-20 23:25    00:18:00    10.97   $49.00
```

Comment: It should be taking both the date and time. Date and time are mere numbers in excel formatted to appear into a useful way. What is your data and the results you're currently getting and your expected results?

Comment: there is the data. and the results are off, becuase its calculating a price from 2013-09-23 6:00 which its not suppossed to its supposed to be cut off at 4 am.

Comment: I cannot replicate what you're getting. See in this [excel file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/M%20of%20CA.xlsx). I introduced one for date `2013-09-23 6:00` but it's not being summed in the formula...

Comment: yes yours works. so i took ur file and expanded the data, and moved it into another sheet. https://db.tt/rlZBJn2N. and back to the same problem. what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Check row 36 in Sheet4: it has 2013-09-23 00:28 (which is midnight on the 23rd, which is before 4 in the morning).

Comment: damn...... that was the issue. man, i have been at this for hoursssss.

Comment: It's okay :) Your data had be baffled as well when I first saw it ^^

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, there was a type in my data.